# string.IsNullOrEmpty vs string = '' in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, string

What is the different when using string.IsNullOrEmpty and string = ''

```
If  string.IsNullOrEmpty(str) then
   ' do something
End If

If string = "" then
   ' do something
End If
```

Does IsNullorEmpty include ""?

Comment: yes - that is exactly what empty means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [String.IsNullOrEmpty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorempty%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method checks for both `null` and `empty` fields, while `string==""` only checks for `empty` fields.

If a string is not defined, it will be `null` by default. Therefore, it is a better idea to use IsNullOrEmpty.

P.S. `'a'` and `"a"` is different. The single quote is used for characters while double quotes are used for strings.

Answer (score 1):

This is a good reference for the built-in function IsNullorEmpty of the String class:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorempty(v=vs.110).aspx

The difference is that the latter uses a built-in function to return True or False in checking strings if they are empty. Basically the second condition is a straight-forward checking of a String if it is empty.

IsNullorEmpty does not include " in its syntax. Hope that helps.